# Inserting data into two tables resulting in "Array to string conversion"

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm trying to create a form for my system, user could add the numbers of input fields, the input fields are mostly drop down box with the options coming from tables in the database. The forms would insert the data into two different database. But it shows error of "Array to string conversion" Right now the data only inserted into the first table. Here's what I'd done so far

My form's code:

```
<form method="post" name="maklumat_akaun" action="proses_daftar_akaun.php">



                    <label for="NoAkaun">No. Akaun</label> 
                    <input type="text" id="NoAkaun" name="NoAkaun" class="required input_field" required/> 
                    <div class="cleaner_h10"></div> 




                    <label for="KodDaerah">Daerah</label>
                    <?php
                    include('dbase.php');$sql   = "SELECT KodDaerah, NamaDaerah FROM koddaerah";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql);
                    echo "<select name='KodDaerah' id='KodDaerah' class='input_field' required /><option></option>";
                    while($kod = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                    echo "<option value=".$kod['KodDaerah'].">" .$kod['NamaDaerah']."</OPTION>";
                    }
                    echo "</select>";
                    ?>  
                    <div class="cleaner_h10"></div> 



                    <label for="KodBahagian">Bahagian</label>
                    <?php
                    $sql    = "SELECT KodBahagian, NamaBahagian FROM kodbahagian";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql);
                    echo "<select name='KodBahagian' id='KodBahagian' class='input_field' required /><option></option>";
                    while($kod = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                    echo "<option value=".$kod['KodBahagian'].">" .$kod['NamaBahagian']."</OPTION>";
                    }
                    echo "</select>";
                    ?>  
                    <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>


                    <label for="KodKategori">Kategori Akaun</label>                        
                    <?php
                    $sql    = "SELECT KodKategori, NamaKategori , SubKategori FROM kodkategori";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql);
                    echo "<select name='KodKategori' id='KodKategori' class='input_field' required /><option></option>";
                    while($kod = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                    echo "<option value=".$kod['KodKategori'].">" .$kod['NamaKategori']." (".$kod['SubKategori'].")</OPTION>";
                    }
                    echo "</select>";
                    ?>                  
                    <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>








                    <label for="Tarif">Tarif</label>
                    <input type="text" maxlength="4" size="4" id="Tarif" name="Tarif" class="required year_field"  onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'')">
                    <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>







<!-----------------------------------------------------------//-->  
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 25; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initial text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div>'+
                                '<td> <?php
                                $sql  = "SELECT KodLokasi, NamaLokasi FROM kodlokasi";
                                $result = mysql_query($sql);
                                echo "<select name=\'KodLokasi[]\' id=\'KodLokasi[]\' class=\'input_field\' required ><option></option>";
                                while($kod = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                                echo "<option value=".$kod['KodLokasi'].">" .$kod['NamaLokasi']. "</OPTION>";
                                }
                                echo "</select>";
                                ?> </td> </tr>'+

                                '<tr> <td> <?php
                                $sql  = "SELECT KodJenisAkaun, NamaJenisAkaun FROM kodjenisakaun";
                                $result = mysql_query($sql);
                                echo "<select name=\'KodJenisAkaun[]\' id=\'KodJenisAkaun[]\' class=\'input_field\' required ><option></option>";
                                while($kod = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                                echo "<option value=".$kod['KodJenisAkaun'].">" .$kod['NamaJenisAkaun']. "</OPTION>";
                                }
                                echo "</select>";
                                ?> </td>'+


                                '<td> <input type="text" name="NoTelefon[]" id="NoTelefon[]" value="0" class="required input_field"> </td>' +

                                '<a href="#" class="remove_field">Batal</a></tr></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    });
});

</script>


                        <fieldset>

                        <div class="input_fields_wrap">
                        <h3 class="add_field_button"><a href="">Add More Fields</a></h3>  


        <table>
        <tr>
            <td> <label for="KodLokasi">Lokasi</label> </td> <td> <label for="KodJenisAkaun">Jenis Akaun</label> </td> <td> <label>No.Telefon:</label> </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td>    <?php 
                    $sql    = "SELECT KodLokasi, NamaLokasi FROM kodlokasi";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql);
                    echo "<select name='KodLokasi[]' id='KodLokasi' class='input_field' required /><option></option>";
                    while($kod = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                    echo "<option value=".$kod['KodLokasi'].">" .$kod['NamaLokasi']."</OPTION>";
                    }
                    echo "</select>";
                    ?>
            </td>


            <td>    <?php
                    $sql    = "SELECT KodJenisAkaun, NamaJenisAkaun FROM kodjenisakaun";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql);
                    echo "<select name='KodJenisAkaun[]' id='KodJenisAkaun' class='input_field' required /><option></option>";
                    while($kod = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                    echo "<option value=".$kod['KodJenisAkaun'].">" .$kod['NamaJenisAkaun']."</OPTION>";
                    }
                    echo "</select>";
                    ?>
            </td>       

            <td> <input type="text" name="no_telefon[]" value="0" class="required input_field" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'')"> </td>                    

        </tr>

        </table>


                        </div>




                        </fieldset>
<!-----------------------------------------------------------//-->                          

                        <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>
                        <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>             


                        <input type="submit" value="Daftar" id="submit" name="register-submit" class="submit_btn" /> 
                        <input type="reset" value="Batal" id="reset" name="reset" class="submit_btn" /> 


                    </table>
                    </form>
```

While this is my code for the inserting process.

```
<?php
require("dbase.php"); 

if ($_POST) {

    $NoAkaun            = isset($_POST['NoAkaun'])          ? $_POST['NoAkaun'] : '';
    $KodBahagian        = isset($_POST['KodBahagian'])      ? $_POST['KodBahagian'] : '';
    $Tarif              = ISSET($_POST['Tarif'])            ? $_POST['Tarif'] : '';
    $KodDaerah          = isset($_POST['KodDaerah'])        ? $_POST['KodDaerah'] : '';
    $KodKategori        = isset($_POST['KodKategori'])      ? $_POST['KodKategori'] : '';
    $NoTelefon          = isset($_POST['NoTelefon'])        ? $_POST['NoTelefon'] : '';
    $KodLokasi          = isset($_POST['KodLokasi'])        ? $_POST['KodLokasi'] : '';
    $KodJenisAkaun      = isset($_POST['KodJenisAkaun'])    ? $_POST['KodJenisAkaun'] : '';
    $akaun_idAkaun      = isset($_POST['akaun_idAkaun'])    ? $_POST['akaun_idAkaun'] : '';




    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO maklumatakaun VALUES ('', '$NoAkaun'  , '$KodBahagian' , '$KodDaerah' , '$KodKategori' ,  '$Tarif' )");
    $akaun_idAkaun = mysql_insert_id();
    foreach ($NoTelefon AS $i => $telefon) {
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO detailakaun VALUES   ('',  '$KodLokasi[$i]', '$KodJenisAkaun' , '$telefon' , '$akaun_idAkaun' )");
}



    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('AKAUN BERJAYA DIDAFTARKAN')</script> ";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='pilih_kategori_daftar.php'</script>";
}


?>
```

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

The error "Array to string conversion" means you are using an array as a string somewhere in your code.  That error message is usually followed by a filename and line number which should help you narrow down your search.  One helpful way to see what is contained within a variable is to use the following:

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($stuff); die();
```

If the error is happening on a line inside of a while loop you should put the echo '' before the while and the die(); after so that you can see all instances of the problem within the loop.

Comment: it was this line sir"    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO detailakaun VALUES   ('',  '$KodLokasi[$i]', '$KodJenisAkaun' , '$telefon' , '$akaun_idAkaun' )"); "

Comment: and no, it is not inside a while loop, but inside if ($_POST)

Answer (score 0):

I found your problem on this statement

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO detailakaun VALUES   ('',  '$KodLokasi[$i]', '$KodJenisAkaun' , '$telefon' , '$akaun_idAkaun' )");
```

`$KodJenisAkaun` is an array and you use it as a string

Comment: I've changed it to $KodJenisAkaun[$i] to help that, and no more error " Array String Conversion" but the only the 1st SQL work. The data only insert into the first table

Comment: Hi @itsfawwaz, I think you should check the number of elements in `$NoTelefon`

Comment: what do you mean by number of elements sir? I have no idea what to fix

Comment: Hi @itsfawwaz, you say that **The data only insert into the first table** so I think `$NoTelefon` has zero element and second SQL could not execute. You can use `echo count($NoTelefon)` to show the number of elements of `$NoTelefon`.

If `$NoTelefon` has one or more than one elements, I think you should check SQL error

`foreach ($NoTelefon AS $i => $telefon) {
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO detailakaun VALUES   ('',  '$KodLokasi[$i]', '$KodJenisAkaun' , '$telefon' , '$akaun_idAkaun' )");
    echo mysql_error();
}`

Comment: As my comment above, you can check your SQL statement, use `mysql_error()` to show MySQL error

Comment: It stated that array to string conversion "cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraints fail

Comment: Ok. Your problem is shown `cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraints fail`. You should fix this.

Comment: So i've fix it by inserting the foreign key manually, and it now allows data to be inserted but out of nowhere the value for KodLokasi and NoTelefon is not what i inserted and it only inserted one row of data

Comment: I understand your problem but I can't give you any ideal because I don't know your system. I think you should review flow, logic and code.